# Jenkinspipeline script to run SpringBoot application remotely

Tags: linux, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins slave node which is windows machine.Now i build a springboot application in my wondows machine,create a JAR file,then SCP this JAR to AIX server and run this JAR in AIX server.

Below is my Jenkins pipeline script looks like

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'Executionmachine3'}

stages {
    stage('SCP JAR file') {
        steps {
            bat "scp ${env.WORKSPACE}\\build\\libs\\SSUP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar rxx11pp@G0XXXX209:/usr/SB/ado/"
           bat "rxx11pp@G0XXXX209 /home/rxx11pp/runspbt.sh"
        }
    }
}}
```

Script runspbt.sh is below

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$(ps -ef | grep -i SSUP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  | grep -v 'grep' | wc | awk {'print $1'})
echo $var1
echo "The name of the file is $var1"

if [ $var1 -eq 0 ]
then
     echo "Going in If"
     java -jar /usr/SB/ado/SSUP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
else
     echo "Going in else"
     sudo ps -ef| grep -i SSUP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -v 'grep' | awk {'print $2'} | head -1 | 
     xargs kill -9
     java -jar /usr/SB/ado/SSUP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
fi
```

The idea here is if the JAR is already running then kill the earlier task and then run the new JAR.

But the problem i am facing here is when the java -jar command runs,the application starts and the Jenkins job never ends.I Was expecting the jenkins job to be completed once it runs the JAR.

Answer (score 1):

I know how to create the daemon thread in java and run the jar in the background but if you want to work with shell script then you need to run it as daemon.

** Updated the answer below **

First create the shell script that will run your spring boot application and then make it executable with the below command

```
chmod +x <your_script>.sh
```

Then create a file in .service at the below location

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

`<your_script>.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description="Running Spring Boot Application"

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=<path>/<your_script>.sh
Restart=on-failure
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start the service by using the below command

```
systemctl start <your_script>.service
```

** Added Boot Executor **

**Maven Dependency**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Source Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

public class Application 
{

    private Options options = null;
    private CommandLineParser cmdParser = null;
    private File appPath = null;

    {
        options = new Options();
        options.addOption("f","file",true,"Path of the spring boot application");
    }


    private void parserCmdLine(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing Command Line Parser...");
        cmdParser = new DefaultParser();
        try 
        {
            run( cmdParser.parse(options, args) );
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( "[ ParseException ]" + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void run(CommandLine cmdLine) 
    {

        System.out.println("Verifying command line options...");

        if(cmdLine.hasOption('f'))
        {
            System.out.println("Short file option found!");
            appPath = new File(cmdLine.getOptionValue('f'));
        }
        else if( cmdLine.hasOption("file") )
        {
            System.out.println("Long file option found!");
            appPath = new File(cmdLine.getOptionValue("file"));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("The specified option does not exist.");
        }

        if( appPath.exists() )
        {
            System.out.println("Spring boot application exists at the following location: " + appPath.getAbsolutePath());
            Thread daemonThread = new Thread( new Runnable() 
            {

                public void run() 
                {
                    System.out.println("Configuring command...");
                    List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
                    command.add("java");
                    command.add("-jar");
                    command.add(appPath.getAbsolutePath());

                    System.out.println("Initializing process builder to start the execution of spring boot application...");
                    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                    processBuilder.directory(new File(appPath.getParent()));

                    System.out.println("Inherited...");
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Starting spring boot Application...");
                        Process process = processBuilder.start();
                        process.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("Exited");

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });

            daemonThread.setDaemon(true);
            daemonThread.start();

            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Boot Executor started...");
        new Application().parserCmdLine(args);
    }
}
```

You can create a jar file and then you can pass argument as follows:

```
--file <path of the spring boot jar>
```

I would suggest try to use the previous solution because we always try to avoid the execution of task that deals with IO using daemon thread.

Comment: How to run it as deamon ?

Comment: You can even check for nohup in case you want do some R&Dd

Comment: Is there any way to handle this from jenkins pipeline ? Like after running the script i mark job as complete forcefully

Comment: I am afraid to say that there is no such option available as of now. Because when you run springboot jar then it hangs the console of Jenkins too because of the embedded tomcat. I usually do the deployment of springboot application with docker.

Comment: If you want then I can create an executor in java that could help you to run the springboot application in the background.

Comment: It would be great help if you can tell how to create this executor.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it out :)

Comment: A side note: there's no systemd on AIX

Comment: Thanks mate. I am not much aware of AIX :) but java code could help him to achieve the requirement. Thanks for sharing the knowledge.